# POST Request returning wrong answer using apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is my apex code

```
        String id = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User activeUser = [Select Email From User where id = :id limit 1];           

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://clozer.3spire.at/checkUser');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody('email='+activeUser.Email);
        req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        }

        System.debug('=============================new deal created ======================================'+res.getBody());
```

On the system log it's showing wrong answer.I send the same requesting using postmaster and the result is appropriate.

System Log
[image]

Postmaster
[image]

Why the result is displaying wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can set ur endpoint as req.setEndpoint('http://clozer.3spire.at/checkUser?email='activeUser.Email); This may fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

An email address of e.g.:

```
abc@def.com
```

when URL encoded is:

```
abc%40def.com
```

so adding encoding may help:

```
req.setBody('email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(activeUser.Email, 'UTF-8'));
```

as the default encoding for POST is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I would also try removing this as it doesn't seem relevant:

```
req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000
```

and perhaps the remote server doesn't accept compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

believe you need to pass the email parameter in the url instead of passing it in the request body similar to what you are doing in postmaster.

```
req.setEndpoint('http://clozer.3spire.at/checkUser/email='+activeUser.Email);
req.setMethod('POST');
```

Comment: i saw some other posts that showing "how to send post request".they do it the way i do